# Angular directives: pass output from fist directive as input of second directive from TEMPLATE

Tags: angular

I have 2 Angular directives: "dmKeyDownDetect" that detects an input and "dmKeyDownReact" that reacts with an action. When the first detects certain inputs (like '/', or 'Escape'), it needs to send that value to the second directive.

I managed to achieve that applying both directives in the template of a component: the first directive has an output (@Output() exactKeyDownDetected: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();) that sends the value to a variable "lastKeyDown" of that component and then the components sends it to "dmKeyDownReact", like this:

```
<input
  dmKeyDownDetect [detect]="['/']" (exactKeyDownDetected)="changeLastKeyDown($event)"
  [dmKeyDownReact]="lastKeyDown" [action]="actionToDo"... >
```

Now, I would like to achieve the same directly from the template (basically the 2 lines here above), to remove the need of going through the component and creating an extra variable just to track the value. I imagine it to be something like:

```
<input
  dmKeyDownDetect [detect]="['/']"
  [dmKeyDownReact]="(exactKeyDownDetected)" [action]="actionToDo"
```

where [dmKeyDownReact]="(exactKeyDownDetected)" should accomplish taking the output from"dmKeyDownDetect" and sending it as input to "dmKeyDownReact".

Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with the help of template variables and exportAs

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[dmKeyDownDetect]',
  exportAs: 'dmKeyDownDetect'
})
class MyDirective {
  lastKeyDown; // will be updated during event handling
}
....
<input
  dmKeyDownDetect #detectDir="dmKeyDownDetect" [detect]="['/']"
  [dmKeyDownReact]="detectDir.lastKeyDown" [action]="actionToDo">
```

Comment: That works neatly, thanks!
I still have a little problem tho. I'm tracking the keyDown changes with "lastKeyDown" as you suggested, and react to them in my second directive with "onChanges". But if I press the same key twice (ie. I press '8', and then '8' again), "lastKeyDown" will stay the same and the value won't be passed from the first to the second directive.
Do you have any idea on how to solve that?

Comment: this was the issue with your previous soluition as well, because how change detection works. you can implement the thing in another way. exportAs in "react" directive and do `(exactKeyDownDetected)="reactDir.update($event)"`